# Orders are not displaying on first render but when I press Ctrl+S(Save) orders are displayed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, hybrid-mobile-app

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import {View, Text, StyleSheet, FlatList, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
import Card from '../components/Card';
import {useState} from 'react';
 
import {useIsFocused} from '@react-navigation/native';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
 
const Orders = ({route, navigation}) => {
 const [userID, setUserID] = useState('');
 const [orders, setOrders] = useState([]);
 const isFocused = useIsFocused();
 
 async function getData() {
   try {
     const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('UserID');
     if (value !== null) {
       console.log('USERID is ' + value);
       setUserID(value);
     }
   } catch (e) {}
 }
 
 function fetchOrders() {
   fetch(
     'https://somewebsite/product/GetOrdersByUserID?userid=' +
       //'1249b39a-ded0-4522-a263-f905ac30e5a3',
       userID,
   )
     .then(response => response.json())
     .then(responseJson => {
       setOrders(responseJson);
     })
     .catch(error => {
       console.error(error);
     });
 }
 getData();
 
 useEffect(() => {
    //getData();
   fetchOrders();
   console.log('UserID inside useffect:: ' + userID);
 
   console.log('inside useEffect');
 }, [isFocused]);
 
 return (
   <View>
     <View style={styles.container}>
       <FlatList
         scrollEnabled={true}
         data={orders}
         renderItem={({item}) => (
           <TouchableOpacity
             onPress={() => {
               navigation.navigate('OrderDetails', {
                 orderID: item.id,
               });
             }}>
             <View style={styles.viewPP}>
               <Card style={styles.cardPP}>
                 <Text style={styles.text}>Order ID:{item.id}</Text>
                 <Text style={styles.text}>Total: ₹{item.total}</Text>
                 <Text style={styles.text}>Placed: {item.placed}</Text>
                 <Text style={styles.text}>Status: Delivered</Text>
               </Card>
             </View>
           </TouchableOpacity>
         )}></FlatList>
     </View>
   </View>
 );
};
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 container: {
   padding: 10,
 },
 
 text: {
   fontWeight: 'bold',
   alignContent: 'center',
 },
 cardPP: {
   margin: 10,
 },
});
export default Orders;
```

My issue is I am not getting the UserID on first render but when I press Ctrl+S(Save operation) I am able to get the UserID and hence the Orders are displayed.
My issue is I am not able to fetch the UserID on first render.
I have tried console.log(UserID) and it's blank the first time as above.
When I put the UserID directly as 1249b39a-ded0-4522-a263-f905ac30e5a3 in 'https://somewebsite/product/GetOrdersByUserID?userid=' inside fetchOrders() Orders are displayed without any issue on the First render.
Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

State updates are not synchronous. Like if you call setUserId, it doesn't synchronously set the state, for you to consume it instantly. It's managed asynchronously through React internally. Better if you follow your Promises and pass parameters, etc. Let me know if I missed anything

```js
const Orders = ({route, navigation}) => {
 const [userID, setUserID] = useState('');
 const [orders, setOrders] = useState([]);
 const isFocused = useIsFocused();
 
 async function getData() {
   try {
     const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('UserID');
     if (value !== null) {
       console.log('USERID is ' + value);
       setUserID(value);
       return value;
     }
     throw new ReferenceError("UserID is null");

   } catch (e) {
     return '';
   }
 }
 
 function fetchOrders(userId) {
   fetch(
     'https://somewebsite/product/GetOrdersByUserID?userid=' +
       //'1249b39a-ded0-4522-a263-f905ac30e5a3',
       userID,
   )
     .then(response => response.json())
     .then(responseJson => {
       setOrders(responseJson);
     })
     .catch(error => {
       console.error(error);
     });
 }
 
 useEffect(() => {
   getData()
   .then((v) => fetchOrders(v));
 }, [isFocused]);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This helped me.